# PHP: Use getimagesize to enter image dimensions in database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a number of images who's information is stored in a MySQL database. The images themselves are stored in a folder, but the database contains their URL as well as other pertinent data.

I came across the PHP `getimagesize` which I was thinking of using to populate the `width=` and `height=` properties of the `img` tags of each image. However, I have been told that the overhead for this (as there are hundreds of images) will slow down the page load substantially.

I'm curious if there is a way to use `getimagesize` to search out all the images from their information in the database, calculate their `width` and `height`, and then insert the data into their respective `width` and `height` fields *in* the database, Thus allowing a simple sql query to do the work?

Here is my database structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `secondary_images` (
  `imgId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `primaryId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `imgURL` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `width` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `height` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imgId`),
  KEY `primaryId` (`primaryId`),
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$image_folder = "images/";
$res = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM secondary_images')
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) {
    $size = getimagesize($image_folder.$row['imgUrl']);
    mysql_query("UPDATE secondary_images SET width='{$size[0]}', height='{$size[1]} WHERE imgId='{$row['imgId']}'");
}
```

Why do you want to put image size in html anyway?

Comment: Don't do this...you are trying connect to internet to do the getimagesize. This should be done locally by replacing the imgUrl + document root

Comment: @grisevg - Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I will test, and let you know!

Comment: @ajreal - I don't fully understand what you mean. It will be done locally, however the url's are relative to the PHP page, so wouldn't that be fine? Could you post an answer with what you think would be a better method?

Comment: @ajreal I'm not getting your point. I'm connecting to db(which should be local) to get list of images and them update them o_0

Comment: `getimagesize(/folder/image_url)` is a call to local file system. While `getimagesize('http://your_host.com/image_url')` is calling to internet

Comment: @stefmikhail Again, why do you want to put real size of an image to an  `img` tag?

Comment: @ajreal good point actually. But it depend on how exactly image url is stored. @stefmikhail give as an example of `imgUrl`

Comment: @grisevg - Don't you put the `width` & `height` attributes in your images tags? While the images will indeed load to their correct dimensions without said attributes, the html will not allow for the correct amount of space on the page *before* the images load. See what I'm talking about?

Comment: @stefmikhail I guess.. I just never cared that content is shifted when page loads or I just hid with a fancy loader animation while it loads. Again, give an example of `imgUrl`

Comment: @grisevg - hmmm i suppose I could just use a loader animation, but in this case, because the number of images per page is variable via ajax, and I don't want to hide the whole page every ajax refresh, I think this is the best rout. Thanks for the idea though. And again, thanks for the answer! This should overwrite any previous values, correct?

Comment: @grisevg - Curious if you could amend your answer to print the results of the query, so I can see right there on the page what has been done?

Comment: @stefmikhail Yes this snippet will update ALL record in `secondary_images` table. Print SQL query if you want to see it. Again, @stefmikhail could yoou give an example of `imgUrl`? It's pretty important in what way you store them!

Comment: @grisevg - So sorry! I've been out and as such just got your comment now. I'm storing the URL by just the file name as both the thumbnail *and* the large image have the same file name, just in a different directory. I'm assuming you're wanting to know this as I will have to put the rest of the path in the `getimagesize` query? I'm wondering how I will do that actually...

Comment: @stefmikhail good then. As @ajreal suggested, `imgUrl` `SHOULD NOT` be an http url! Then all you have to do is `$size = getimagesize($image_folder.$row['imgUrl']);`

Comment: @grisevg - Where $folder is defined as the relative path? And sorry, what do I print/echo? I've only ever echoed retrievals from a database, never additions. Would it be the same? And I don't think I'm calling those operations by the right name. I just woke up :p

Comment: @stefmikhail I have no idea what your application file structure is. Just prepend image folder to the $row['imgUrl']. You have to echo string which contains query. For PHP it's only a string. PS:Looks like you're very bad in programming. No offence, but I would suggest you reading some books if you plan to code in future.

Comment: @grisevg - No offence taken. I'm only about two weeks into using PHP or Ajax at all, so yes, I have a lot to learn. Between the books I am reading, and the information fine people like you give me here on stack overflow, I'm learning fast.

Comment: @stefmikhail In my opinion PHP is the worst language to start learning programming. Id recommend you Python. It's not harder to learn than PHP, but it teaching the right way.

Answer (score 0):

This algorithm may help:

1. Write a query that returns the URLs and imgId of images with a width of null
2. For each of those images, use getimagesize() to get their image size
3. Write an update query to update height and width by imageid

That said, I think it would be best to skip the idea of updating when a user hits the page. At some point, the initial insertion of image data is done -- can you use getimagesize() at that time, or perhaps in a separate program which performs the scan independently of your web site?

Comment: My plan is to run this script whenever I upload new photo information to the database, so that the width and height can be entered in their respective fields in the database. What do you think of grisevg's answer above? And I think the separate program you are speaking of, is exactly what I'm attempting to do.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to get size of image(s) if you don't want to use getimagesize(). I think it is fast enough when they're saved locally

Comment: Also, if all the process is going to be done once, I would not worry at all.

Comment: @genesis - Sorry, I think you misunderstood. I'm not asking if there is another method to get the dimensions of images. I'm asking if there is a method to use `getimagesize` to find the size of the images, and then populate the database with that information so it is saved ahead of me making the site live. Does that make sense?